# Check if WPF DataRowView contains a column

Tags: wpf, datarow

I can get the value of a column in a DataRowView using

```
DataRowView row;
object value = row["MyColumn"];
```

of course, if there is no "MyColumn" in the DataRowView, this code throws an exception.

How do I check in advance, if the row contains "MyColumn"? Sadly there is no row.Contains("MyColumn") on DataRowView.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this

```
dataRowView.Row.Table.Columns.Contains("MyColumn")
```